# List Index out of range error. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lst = []
for i in range(1,13196):
    if 13195 % i == 0:
        lst.append(i)
for k in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(1,lst[k]):
        if lst[k] % j != 0:
            lst.remove(lst[k])
print(lst)
```

When I run this code, it says if `lst[k] % j != 0: List index out of range`. 
Can anyone tell me what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over a range of the *current* length of `lst`. Every time you do `lst.remove(lst[k])`, the `lst` gets shorter, so the range you were using becomes unsuitable. For example, if you start with 8 elements, it goes from indices of `0` to `7` inclusive, but if you remove an element, the last index will then be `6`, not `7`.

The easiest way to fix this is to simply create a new `list`:

```
lst = []
for i in range(1,13196):
    if 13195 % i == 0:
        lst.append(i)

result = lst[:] # create a copy to work with
for k in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(1,lst[k]):
        if lst[k] % j != 0 and lst[k] in result: # check that it's there before removal
            result.remove(lst[k])

print(result)
```

That said, this code eliminates every number which cannot be evenly divided by every positive integer smaller than that number, which understandably produces a result of `[1]`. If that's not what you wanted, you'll have to take another look at your algorithm.

Comment: I wanted to find prime factors of the number

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = []
lst2 = []
for i in range(1,13196):
    if 13195 % i == 0:
        lst.append(i)
        lst2.append(i)

for k in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(1,lst[k]):
        if lst[k] % j != 0: 
            lst2.remove(lst[k])

print lst2
```

Give this a try. Your problem is that you were iterating over the value of the *original* list. When you removed parts of the original list, the length of this value shortened, but the `for` loop will not account for it.